# Managing enum types among configurations of assemblies

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, compilation, conditional-statements

The source code is in C# and there is a lot of legacy code. I use Winforms with a GUI.

I use the source code to build the an assembly but this assembly is included in two different packages. One package is the free demo application (FApp) everyone can download and the second package is the not free and more professional application (ProApp). So you understand that the 2 packages don't have the same set of functionalities.

One defined an enum type in ProApp. I have and issue with the FApp because not all the values in the enum are relevant and they must not appear in the forms of the GUI. That is why I tought about conditional compilation. But it causes compilation errors in the methods that are using the enum. The enum is used in many line of code. Now I am not sure it is a good idea.

original code:

```
public enum eCars {Toyota, Honda, Hyundai, BMW, Acura};
```

My not-so-good solution:
    #if FApp
        public enum eCars {Toyota, Honda, Hyundai};
    #else
        public enum eCars {Toyota, Honda, Hyundai, BMW, Acura};
    #endif

Like I said, many compilation errors in the methods using the enum eCars.

```
public static bool IsItHyundai(eCars car)
{
    if (car == eCars.Hyundai)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Can you suggest another solution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to define the Enum in the FApp, and have the ProApp use the SAME Enum as the FApp. You can then use Attributes on the Enumerations that govern usage and behavior. Extension methods that read the attributes decorating each ENUM value would could then be used to dictate behavior.

Here is some sample code for implementation:

```
public class eCarsUsageAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public eCarsUsageAttribute() { }
        public eCarsUsageAttribute(bool allowInFApp = true)
        {
            AllowInFApp = allowInFApp;
        }
        public bool AllowInFApp { get; set; }
    }
    public enum eCars
    {
        [eCarsUsageAttribute]
        Toyota,
        [eCarsUsageAttribute]
        Honda,
        [eCarsUsageAttribute(false)]
        Hyundai,
        [eCarsUsageAttribute]
        BMW,
        [eCarsUsageAttribute]
        Acura
    };
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static bool AllowInFreeApp(this eCars value)
        {
            lock (_usageValues)
            {
                //reflection is somewhat expensive so I'd recommend using a local store to keep the attributes that you have already looked up
                if (!_usageValues.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    // Get the type
                    Type type = value.GetType();

                    // Get fieldinfo for this type
                    System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

                    // Get the stringvalue attributes
                    eCarsUsageAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(eCarsUsageAttribute), false) as eCarsUsageAttribute[];

                    var attr = attribs.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (attr != null)
                        _usageValues[value] = attr.AllowInFApp;
                    else
                        _usageValues[value] = false;//Depends on what you want the default behavior to be

                }
                return _usageValues[value];
            }
        }
        private static Dictionary<eCars, bool> _usageValues = new Dictionary<eCars, bool>();
    }
```

Comment: But how would you define the method IsItHyundai?

Comment: @Smurf That method implementation would not change. The Enum value would exist in both application environments because they would share an implementation - so the compiler would not have an issue with it. Changes would need to be made in OTHER parts of the application to prevent usage of eCars that are flagged as unavailable.